# WinJS.xhr error while executing second time

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

Test sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Getting-started-with-310271df

I am facing some absurd issue with *`WinJS.xhr`* call. Below sample if you run it works for the first time. However, next time onwards it gives this error!

```
Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library 
code at line 2351, column 21 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js

0x800c0008 - JavaScript runtime error: The download of the specified 
resource has failed.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."
```

Now if I delete the debug folder it just works fine again for me. 
This is the same case as well if I install it.

Comment: I got it solved by adding html header with no-caching

Comment: return WinJS.xhr({
            url: url1,
            headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache", "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 27 Mar 1972 00:00:00 GMT" }
        });

Comment: add it as an answer so it can be set as resolved and maybe help others

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
return WinJS.xhr({ url: myUrl, headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache"} });
```